# looping over local map of bojects with for expression on a resouce that already has a for_loop

Tags: terraform

How could i achieve looping over local.daily map so i could create the backup policy name based on the map value on a resource that already uses a for_each loop ?

On the following example, on the resource azurerm_backup_policy_file_share i would like to populate the name field with the value of local.daily["name"] value.

```
locals {
  regions = [
    "centralus",
    "northeurope"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "recovery_vault" {
  name     = "recovery-vault-${terraform.workspace}-rg"
  location = var.azure_region
  tags = {
    environment = terraform.workspace
    source      = "terraform"
    service     = "Backup Vault"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vaults" {
  for_each            = toset(local.regions)
  name                = "recovery-vault-${terraform.workspace}-${each.key}"
  location            = each.key
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.recovery_vault.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  soft_delete_enabled = true
}



locals {
  daily = [{
    name      = "Every23h"
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
    count = 30
    }
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_file_share" "daily" {
  for_each            = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vaults
  name                = "need this field to be name retrieved from local.daily"
  resource_group_name = each.value["resource_group_name"]
  recovery_vault_name = each.value["name"]
  timezone            = "UTC"


  dynamic "backup" {
    for_each = local.daily
    content {
      frequency = backup.value["frequency"]
      time      = backup.value["time"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "retention_daily" {
    for_each = local.daily
    content {
      count = retention_daily.value["count"]
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Your ```daily``` is a list with just one element. In this case could you not simply use this one element, without any loops. I.e. ```local.dailys[0].name```. If so, you could also make your ```daily``` directly a map rather than a list of maps (i.e. drop the ```[``` and ```]``` in the definition of your ```daily```.
If you really want to have a list there: what do you want the name of your ```azurerm_backup_policy_file_share``` to be? Something like a concatenation? Or do you want to have more resources, one per name and region?

Comment: @FalkTandetzky at the moment is just one element but it will expand,  more, weekly, monthly, etc.. this is just a barebone for a larger implementation. On the example, daily will have a subset of many other timewindow during the 24 hours. for my specific scenario, i just want to use the name "Every23h" or any value on the name key for the amout of values that i need to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html).
It should look something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_backup_policy_file_share" "daily" {
  for_each  = toset(setproduct(azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vaults, local.daily))

  name  = each.value[1].name
  resource_group_name = each.value[0]["resource_group_name"]
  # ...
```